# try restarting transaction erro while add a product?

Tags: magento-1.9

While adding a product in local system i got this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

How i fix it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded

Comment: this is local system not live pack